# Prevent glob expansion in foo="*"; echo $foo

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards

In Bash, when I do:

```
foo="*"
echo $foo
```

It expands `*` to the contents of the current folder. How do I make sure it just prints a literal `*`?

The same, by the way, happens with a regular `echo "$foo"`, it prints the contents of the current folder.

Comment: Thanks @don_crissti: It works, but it prints the contents of the current folder.

Comment: @don_crissti My wrong! Sorry I read that too quickly. Can't believe I fell  victim to this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let us define `foo`:

```
$ foo="*"
```

Now, try echo without quotes:

```
$ echo $foo
File1 File2
```

The replacement of `*` with a list of filenames is called *pathname expansion*.  It can be suppressed with with double-quotes:

```
$ echo "$foo"
*
```

In addition, double-quotes will prevent *brace expansion*, *tilde expansion*, and *word splitting*.

For completeness, try echo with single quotes:

```
$ echo '$foo'
$foo
```

Single quotes prevent the shell from making any substitutions at all.

Comment: Of course! I can't believe I missed this. I kept thinking of quoting the original assignment, not the expansion on the echo statement itself!